# Why would setting a view's frame cause float imprecision?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, cgrect

I'm running into a very weird float imprecision when assigning a `CGRect` to a view frame. I could narrow down the reproduction steps to this:

#### Assigning frame with different size

```
CGRect frame = self.label.frame;
frame.origin.x = 13.f;
NSLog(@"boundingRect = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(boundingRect));
frame.size = boundingRect.size;
NSLog(@"Before assignment, x=%f", frame.origin.x);
self.label.frame = frame;
NSLog(@"After assignment, x=%f", self.label.frame.origin.x);
```

Output:

```
boundingRect = {{0, 0}, {116.072, 13.123}}
Before assignment, x=13.000000
After assignment, x=12.999996 <= ???
```

#### Assigning frame without changing the source size

```
CGRect frame = self.label.frame;
frame.origin.x = 13.f;
//NSLog(@"boundingRect = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(boundingRect));
//frame.size = boundingRect.size;
NSLog(@"Before assignment, x=%f", frame.origin.x);
self.label.frame = frame;
NSLog(@"After assignment, x=%f", self.label.frame.origin.x);
```

Output:

```
Before assignment 13.000000
After assignment 13.000000
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: What system are you running? (OS X 10.? x86, Xcode v.?, iOS ?, Simulator or Device, etc.)

Comment: What are `boundingRect` and `self.label`?

Comment: iPhone Retina (4inch) simulator (not x64), OSX 10.9.4. `boundingRect` is a `CGRect` computed after a `NSString boundingRectWithSize...`, `self.label` is an instance of `UILabel`.